# Clarification on “Who stars opposite X in some film?”

Tags: phrase-meaning

I’ve always understood the phrase

> Who stars opposite [x] in [film]?

to mean:

> Who is the deuteragonist in [film]?

specifically where the deuteragonist is on the same side as the protagonist.

Can it also mean this:

> Who is the antagonist in [film]?

Comment: Yes.  But it can also merely mean someone who was also in the film.  Publicists think "starred opposite Tom Hanks in the film..." is more impressive than "had a bit part in the film...".

Comment: "Stars opposite" typically means a co-star who is the opposite gender of the star.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can mean both starring as an opposing villian or as another star but on the side of the protagonist. It’s an expression that basically means the “who” is a major star in the film, with a key role connected to the “opposite” star.

Doing a quick lookup of the term *deuteragonist*, such a role can be filled by the antagonist.  The basic idea behind the expression is that “X” actor interacts significantly with “Y” actor, their position as being on the side of or against the protagonist notwithstanding.

See [the second definition given for *deuteragonist* in Merriam-Webster’s online access](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deuteragonist).

---

1: the actor taking the part of second importance in a classical Greek drama

**2: a person who serves as a foil to another**

---

It’s usually reserved for a film where two major stars are being featured.  As a relatively recent example, you could say the following:

> In *The Dark Knight*, Heath Ledger starred opposite of Christian Bale in his role of The Joker.

As an example from a non-villainous role:

> Jai Courtney stars opposite of Bruce Willis in the most recent Die Hard movie, *A Good Day to Die Hard*.

Answer (score 3):

It’s just a bit of fancy talk to make the person sound awesome.  It can mean everything from *second-most important character* to *antagonist* to *other dude who showed up*.  It depends on the context, because “person A playing opposite person B” can also be written as “person B playing opposite person A”.

[Here’s](http://www.accesshollywood.com/heath-ledger) an example:

> His film career, along with heartthrob status, really took off with 1999’s *10 Things I Hate About You*, in which he starred opposite Julia Stiles.

If you’ve seen the (truly excellent) movie or know the (obviously superior) play it is based upon, you’ll know that their two characters are “enemies” who eventually end up on the same side.